# Norm of an element in a C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

The following is a part of a proof in Takasaki's Operator theory:

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $A$ is a C*-algebra. For an $x\in A$, put $h=x^*x$ and $u_\epsilon=(h+\epsilon)^{-1}h$. We have then $$||x(1-u_\epsilon)^\frac{1}{2}||=||\epsilon x(h+\epsilon)^\frac{-1}{2}||$$$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=\epsilon|| (h+\epsilon)^\frac{-1}{2}x^*x(h+\epsilon)^\frac{-1}{2}||^\frac{1}{2}$$$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=\epsilon||(h+\epsilon)^{-1}h||\leq \epsilon$$

I do not know how he concludes the last equation. I define $u_\epsilon:=(h+\epsilon^2)^{-1}h$, and I think it follows like below,

$$||x(1-u_\epsilon)^\frac{1}{2}||=||\epsilon x(h+\epsilon^2)^\frac{-1}{2}||$$$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=\epsilon|| (h+\epsilon^2)^\frac{-1}{2}x^*x(h+\epsilon^2)^\frac{-1}{2}||^\frac{1}{2}$$$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=\epsilon||(h+\epsilon^2)^{-1}h||^\frac{1}{2}\leq \epsilon$$

Please check my attempt and help me to understand Takasaki's way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You equation looks correct to me. The one you give above does not look right to me, starting with $\epsilon$ instead of $\sqrt{\epsilon}$ and ending with a missing $1/2$ power on the norm.

Comment: @T.A.E. :Yes, I think like you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a typo and my way is correct.